# Angular bundle size not reduced using nx monorepo using --prod and --build-optimizer

Tags: angular, nrwl

I'm trying to reduce/optimise my angular bundle. The problem is that what ever I try, the files in `dist` are always the same size. In my case, the total dist-size is 1.6MB (main.js has a filesize of 430KB)

Here is what I do:

```
$> nx run build:www
```

and

```
$> nx clear-cache   
$> NX_CACHE=skip npm run build:www -- --prod --build-optimizer
```

I also tried without the `--` whithout success. I also noticed, that `NX_CACHE=skip` doesn't seem to do much, thats why I added the `nx clear-cache` to make sure cache is cleared.

Any suggestions

Comment: have you tried using `ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --vendor-chunk=true`

Comment: Nice, `--vendor-chunk=true` seems to do the trick!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting it as an answer so that it may help others:

Please try using the below command:

```
ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --vendor-chunk=true
```